# CodeIgniter4 - Module works fine on localhost but not on production

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

On my code igniter application, I created an internal module (admin).
After configure my .htaccess everything works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But when I send the files to public folder, the route mysite.com/admin not is recognized
I did tons of different configs on htaccess but all return 404 (and here on localmachine works fine). Probably is a problem of apache directives, but I cannot access it (only by .htaccess), any suggestion ?

Comment: did you check naming conventions for files and class names? did you $config[base_url] correctly? You talk about a route, how does it look like, is it set as a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```